Problem with Double Hat and \texorpdfstring in a Section Title
I'm using this version of double hat (in fact, slightly modified for widehat), and I need to type something like $\doublehat{A}$ in the title of a Section, but this produces a nonsense and a number of errors. This is my MWE
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,reqno]{amsart}

\def\measurehat#1{%
   \setbox0=\vbox{$\widehat{#1}\hfil\break$\null\par
      \setbox0=\lastbox\unskip\unpenalty\global\setbox1=\lastbox}%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\unhbox1 \unskip\unpenalty\unskip \global\setbox2=\lastbox}%
   \setbox0=\vbox{\unvbox2 \setbox0=\lastbox}%
}
\def\doublewidehat#1{%
   \measurehat{#1}\dimen0=\wd0 \measurehat{\kern0pt#1}%
   \raise.35ex\rlap{\kern\dimexpr\dimen0-\wd0$\widehat{\phantom{#1}}$}{\widehat#1}%
}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Section Section \texorpdfstring{$\doublewidehat{A}$}{A}}
\end{document}

And this is the pdf

And here are some errors:

You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode.
You can't use `\unpenalty' in vertical mode.
You can't use `\lastbox' in vertical mode.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
You can't use `\raise' in vertical mode.

I suspect that \measurehat and \raise don't work properly, but have no idea how to fix this. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated!

well the first error is that you are not loading hyperref. But beside this use \protected\def\doublewidehat then the command doesn't break on its way into the table of contents. (Or use \NewDocumentCommand\doublewidehat{m}{... code ...}

@UlrikeFischer Thank you so much! \protected\def\doublewidehat works perfectly

Replace \def\doublewidehat#1 with \DeclareRobustCommand\doublewidehat[1]
